# How to pass a array of parameters in dynamic query Life ray?

Tags: hibernate, liferay, dynamicquery

I can able to write dynamic query for id like this

```
DynamicQuery dynamicQuery = DynamicQueryFactoryUtil.forClass(Custoxxxx.class, PortletClassLoaderUtil.getClassLoader();
2dynamicQuery.add(PropertyFactoryUtil.forName("xxxId").eq(new Long(10931));
```

but how to pass array of Ids? 
in dynamic query.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141823/is-cross-posting-wrong-to-an-external-site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `in` instead of `eq`to pass an array or collection. Ex. `2dynamicQuery.add(PropertyFactoryUtil.forName("xxxId").in(Collection<?> values));`

[Property documentation reference](https://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.2/javadocs/com/liferay/portal/kernel/dao/orm/Property.html)